# Why did Fauxnnie try to get Steven to tell the truth?

Tags: steven-universe

In Season 2, Episode 2, Steven and Connie go to Rose Quartz’s room to enact a better ending for the “Unfamiliar Familiar” series.

Steven accidentally creates a faux Connie (“Fauxnnie”), and then orders her not to do what he wants. This results in her following him, for example (when he says he doesn’t want her to follow him).

However, Fauxnnie really seems to want Steven to confess that he likes Connie, and (moreover) that he actually liked the ending of the Unfamiliar Familiar series, and tries to force him to do so. Why is she doing this? He didn’t tell her to do it, or *not* to do it, or that he did or didn’t want to do it. Moreover, after he does these things she seems satisfied and disappears. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common theme in Steven's experiences in the room is that the room tailors things according to his own thoughts and perspective, and tries to give him what he desires and help him through his problems. It is not an oracle that can see truths beyond what Steven himself knows (except that it seems to know the layout of the temple and how to get around it).  It sees into his heart and feelings, and uses his knowledge.

Later in the series he talks to a facsimile of his mom in the room, and remarks about how he knows this isn't his "real mom" and she's just acting like how he wants her to or thinks she should.  The room adjusts her behavior according to his mood and changing emphasis. Initially she's very jovial and motherly, later more dark and menacing, as he switches from seeking a mother's love and comfort to confronting her complicated past and lies, and what that means to him.

[Here's a clip of (the second half of) Steven interacting with his faux-mom in the room.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJ2I688Y30U%20%20Steven%20talks%20with%20his%20faux-mom.)

As such the room seems to have a certain will and desire to help Steven understand himself and his feelings. The function of the room seems to be less "do as verbally commanded", and more "do as commanded by his heart, to help him."  The room senses that Steven is a bit frustrated by his differing opinions on the ending of the series; is fearful that expressing a different opinion from Connie will jeopardize their relationship; and is confused about exactly how he feels about Connie and why he's going through all of this turmoil and not being honest.  The room helps Steven through this by forcing him to acknowledge and confront the issues. Once he does so, the room has successfully followed "his heart's command", and Fauxnnie disappears.